# How to prevent adding new row, to prevent overloading in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Let's say I'm trying to create sample db schema for cinema reservation.
I have a Table "auditorium" with ***int capacity*** and i wish to be able to create as much 'bookings' record, but i want to be unable to create booking when the auditorium is fill.

So for example, lets say Auditiorium A has 100 seats. Then i wish to be able to insert 100 bookings that has FK to Auditorium A, and when i try to create 101'st booking i will have error or something like this.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are different RDBMS, please pick the right tag.

Comment: This would normally be done in the application logic, not the database.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server

Comment: I know MySQL is not the same think as SQL Server... I just thought that if i get solution in mysql i can easily translate it into sql server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would normally be handled by a trigger -- in either MySQL or SQL Server.

One method is to have an `Auditoria` table that has a maximum capacity (or perhaps a maximum per event, if the configuration could change).

The `Bookings` table would have a trigger.  When records are inserted, the number of records for the event would be compared to the capacity for the auditorium, and inserts that exceed the capacity would fail.

If the Auditoria have a fixed capacity and layout, you can also have a table with one row per seat.  The booking would then be for a particular seat -- and the capacity issue is automatically taken care of (because no seats would be available).